# Acess Cell content in onClick function of a Button created in TemplateField

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView with a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnGetInfo" runat="server"  Text="Log Book" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However, I need to send to the `onClick` function the content of the cell right beside this one, which is created using a `DataTable`. How can I access that content (or pass it calling the function) in CodeBehind?

Thanks in advance,
Diogo Santos

Comment: Take a look at:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hrJQ3D6WTw

Answer (score 0):

You can access every control of asp:TemplateField in RowCommand event of GridView like below

GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int index= gvr.RowIndex;

GridViewRow row = GridName.Rows[index];
Label lblresultid = row.FindControl("lbl") as Label; (Typecast into whatever control you are looking for. Replace lbl with your control's ID)